# Laravel 5.5 and React JS: Method move() not found. I'm trying to save files on the server

Tags: javascript, php, json, reactjs, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to send this JSON of files to server, and store there:

[JSON of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjPHT.png)

Here is the code on the server:

```
//ItemsController.php
public function store(Request $request, Items $item, Storage $storage)
{

        //file_put_contents('index.txt',$request);

        $i = 0;
        if ($request->has('files'))
        {
            foreach($request->only('files') as $files){
                foreach($files as $file) {
                    $file->move(storage_path('/id'));
                   // return response()->json($file);
                }
            }
            return response()->json($i);
        }
        return abort(500);
}
```

I have got this error:

```
{message: "Call to a member function move() on array", exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError", file: "W:\domains\reactLaravel\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ItemsController.php", line: 52, trace: Array(43)}
```

Someone have had the same issue?

Comment: WHat makes you think $files is an array of objects?

Comment: because i got this array of two objects from the server back to me

0:{id: "files-1", extension: "jpg", sizeReadable: "116kB", preview: {…}}
1:{id: "files-2", extension: "jpg", sizeReadable: "3MB", preview: {…}}

it's variable $files, $file is the one of them